# Applying modeling matrix to view matrix = failure

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, opentk

I've got a problem with moving and rotating objects in OpenGL. I'm using C# and OpenTK (Mono), but I guess the problem is with me not understanding the OpenGL part, so you might be able to help me even if you don't know anything about C# / OpenTK.

I'm reading the OpenGL SuperBible (latest edition) and I tried to rewrite the [GLFrame](http://code.google.com/p/oglsuperbible5/source/browse/trunk/Src/GLTools/include/GLFrame.h?r=160) in C#. Here is the part I've already rewritten:

```
public class GameObject
{
    protected Vector3 vLocation;
    public Vector3 vUp;
    protected Vector3 vForward;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        vLocation = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        vUp = Vector3.UnitY;
        vForward = Vector3.UnitZ;
    }

    public Matrix4 GetMatrix(bool rotationOnly = false)
    {
        Matrix4 matrix;

        Vector3 vXAxis;
        Vector3.Cross(ref vUp, ref vForward, out vXAxis);

        matrix = new Matrix4();
        matrix.Row0 = new Vector4(vXAxis.X, vUp.X, vForward.X, vLocation.X);
        matrix.Row1 = new Vector4(vXAxis.Y, vUp.Y, vForward.Y, vLocation.Y);
        matrix.Row2 = new Vector4(vXAxis.Z, vUp.Z, vForward.Z, vLocation.Z);
        matrix.Row3 = new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        return matrix;
    }

    public void Move(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        vLocation = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    public void RotateLocalZ(float angle)
    {
        Matrix4 rotMat;

        // Just Rotate around the up vector
        // Create a rotation matrix around my Up (Y) vector
        rotMat = Matrix4.CreateFromAxisAngle(vForward, angle);

        Vector3 newVect;

        // Rotate forward pointing vector (inlined 3x3 transform)
        newVect.X = rotMat.M11 * vUp.X + rotMat.M12 * vUp.Y + rotMat.M13 * vUp.Z;
        newVect.Y = rotMat.M21 * vUp.X + rotMat.M22 * vUp.Y + rotMat.M23 * vUp.Z;
        newVect.Z = rotMat.M31 * vUp.X + rotMat.M32 * vUp.Y + rotMat.M33 * vUp.Z;

        vUp = newVect;
    }
}
```

So I create a new GameObject (GLFrame) on some random coordinates: `GameObject go = new GameObject(0, 0, 5);` and rotate it a bit: `go.RotateLocalZ(rotZ);`. Then I get the matrix using `Matrix4 matrix = go.GetMatrix();` and render frame (first, I set the viewing matrix and then I multiply it with modeling matrix)

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnRenderFrame(e);
    this.Title = "FPS: " + (1 / e.Time).ToString("0.0");

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    GL.LoadIdentity();

    Matrix4 modelmatrix = go.GetMatrix();
    Matrix4 viewmatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(5, 5, -10), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.UnitY);

    GL.LoadMatrix(ref viewmatrix);

    GL.MultMatrix(ref modelmatrix);

    DrawCube(new float[] { 0.5f, 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.8f });

    SwapBuffers();
}
```

The `DrawCube(float[] color)` is my own method for drawing a cube.

Now the most important part: If I render the frame **without** the `GL.MultMatrix(ref matrix);` part, *but* using `GL.Translate()` and `GL.Rotate()`, it works (second screenshot). However, if I don't use these two methods and I pass the modeling matrix directly to OpenGL using `GL.MultMatrix()`, it draws something strange (first screenshot).

[image: How it looks like]
[image: How it should look like]

Can you help me and explain me where is the problem? Why does it work using translate and rotate methods, but not with multiplying the view matrix by the modeling matrix?

Comment: Just a hunch - try using the transpose of the transformation matrix you are using.

Comment: Are you a god? It worked! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so... Its just a good practice to check that before you sink to deep into gl code.

I'll write it as the answer (please accept).

Comment: @TalDarom, if someone asks you if you're a god, you say YES! +1.

Comment: <strike> I don't think so...</strike> Y E S ! Its just a good practice to <strike>check that before you sink to deep into gl code. I'll write it as the answer (please accept).</strike> kneel before your master! @BrettHale, Better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL transformation matrices are ordered column wise. You should use the transpose of the matrix you are using.